# TortoiseHG, is it possible to have the work folder in another place than the repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TortoiseHg change default .hg folder location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504453/tortoisehg-change-default-hg-folder-location)

I'd like to have my working directory (sources files etc) in another folder than my repository. Indeed, otherwise it creates a .hg folder which is indexed in our IDE and it makes everything slower (also problematic when sharing things with coworkers).

Is it possible to have the repository in one folder, and tell TortoiseHG that the files are somewhere else? 
Thanks.

Ps: moving the repository one folder up isn't really a solution, as it then has to index all the config files, objects files, etc...

Comment: What about simply configuring your IDE to ignore the `.hg` folder? Doesn't that sound like a simpler and better solution?

Comment: Thanks @christian, it seems to be a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to separate the `.hg` folder and the working folder.

(You should try to configure your IDE so that it does *not* index the `.hg` folder, like Jon already suggested in his comment)